# git push to trigger file upload to other repository

Tags: git, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm using bitbucket and sourcetree to control version, and pipelines to deploy.

I need to change a file on repository B when a push is made on repository A, from pipeline of repository A.

Any ideas on how to achieve this ?

Just to clarify, the flow is 
1. Push to Repo A. 
2. Run Pipeline for Repo A. 
3. Pipeline pushes a specific file to Repo B.

Comment: Just to clarify, the flow is 1. Push to Repo A. 2. Run Pipeline for Repo A. 3. Pipeline pushes a change to Repo B. Correct?

Comment: Just edited using your flow with a small change